# C# Application crashes, changing viewport on WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading, viewport, dispatcher

I'm new to WPF, My C# application crashes when I call that method more than once, 
I call that method from an android application that changes the ViewPort3D

Thanks for you help!

==============

```
public void markForDelete(int id){
             Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                 new ThreadStart(() =>
                 {
                     foreach (Marker m in markersList)
                     {
                         if (m.id == id)
                         {
                             viewport3D1.Children.Remove(m.model);
                             Point3D centre = m.point;
                             m.markPointDelete(centre);
                             Console.Out.WriteLine(m.id);
                             viewport3D1.Children.Add(m.model);
                         }
                     }

                 }
              )
              );
         }
         }
```

Comment: "That method" meaning the `Children.Remove` and `Children.Add` methods? Or the `markForDelete`? Also include the error stack trace, what does it say about the error?

Comment: the markForDelete, No specific error only the app crashing

Comment: Should have an error message. What is the error type